# Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis requires StackExchange.Redis.StrongName, however StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core requires StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, signalr, strongname, stackexchange, signalr-backplane

Both *Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis* and *StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core* are used in the same project. The former requires **StackExchange.Redis.StrongName**, while the latter has dependency to **StackExchange.Redis**. Obviously, you can't have both **StackExchange.Redis.StrongName** and **StackExchange.Redis** in the same Bin folder.

Is there a way to force *Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis* and *StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core* to both either work with **StackExchange.Redis.StrongName** or **StackExchange.Redis**?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up downloading *StackExchange.Redis.Extensions* solution from Github and building *StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core* with **StackExchange.Redis.StrongName** reference instead of **StackExchange.Redis**.

Interestingly enough, starting with v3 beta, Microsoft is no longer referencing **StackExchange.Redis.StrongName** 
(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Redis/3.0.0-beta3)

```
Dependencies  
ASP.NET 5.0  
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server (>= 3.0.0-beta3)  
Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json (>= 1.0.0-beta3)  
StackExchange.Redis (>= 1.0.394)
```

Comment: They unlisted the 3.0.0-beta3 package, but they added a new package for version 2.4.0 that supports the new StackExchange.Redis. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/11/14/asp-net-signalr-2-4-0/